# Edit a shiny.tag element

Tags: r, shiny

**Background**

I want to change some elements of a `shinydashboard::box`. Say, I want to change the icon used for collapsing a `box(collapsible = TRUE)`. Looking at the output, all I need to do is to change the `<i>` tag accordingly:

```
(b <- box(collapsible = T))
# <div class="col-sm-6">
#   <div class="box">
#    <div class="box-header">
#       <div class="box-tools pull-right">
#         <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
#           <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> ## change to <i class="fa fa-times">
#         </button>
#       </div>
#    </div>
#    <div class="box-body"></div>
#   </div>
# </div>
```

**Challenge**

While I could do some recursive looping through `b$children` to find the right children element like in

```
b$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$attribs$class <- "fa fa-times"
```

I was wondering, whether there is not an easier way? Ideally something resembling `jQuery` syntax?

Another option would be to write my own `box` function, but I want to avoid that code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper function to edit the generated HTML. We could used the functions from `xml2` to parse and edit the html. For example

```
swap_node <- function(x, xpath, newval) {
  parsed <- xml2::read_html(as.character(x))  
  oldnode <- xml2::xml_find_all(parsed, xpath)
  newnode <- xml2::read_html(as.character(newval))
  xml2::xml_replace(oldnode, newnode)
  shiny::HTML(as.character(xml2::xml_find_first(parsed, "//body/*")))
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
b <- shinydashboard::box(collapsible = T)
swap_node(b, "//i", shiny::tags$i(class="fa fa-times"))
```

But this operates in the world of strings rather than objects.

Comment: Ok, very useful indeed, thanks for sharing. I guess I will resort to `jQuery` in this case then. Unless somebody comes up with a solution working on the object rather than the string, I will happily accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that navigates the `shiny` object in the search for a tag of a given type having given attributes. If it is found, it is replaced by a new tag with new attributes:

```
searchreplaceit <- function(branch, whattag, whatattribs, totag, toattribs) {
    if ("name" %in% names(branch)) {
        if ((branch$name == whattag)&&(identical( branch$attribs[names(whatattribs)], whatattribs))) {
            branch$name    <- totag
            branch$attribs <- modifyList(branch$attribs, toattribs)
        }
    }
    if (class(branch)=="shiny.tag") {
        if (length(branch$children)>0) for (i in 1: length(branch$children)) {
            if (!(is.null(branch$children[[i]]))) {
                branch$children[[i]] = searchreplaceit(branch$children[[i]], whattag, whatattribs, totag, toattribs)
        } }
    } else if (class(branch)=="list") {
        if (length(branch)>0) for (i in 1:length(branch) ) {
            if (!(is.null(branch[[i]]))) {
                branch[[i]] <- searchreplaceit(branch[[i]], whattag, whatattribs, totag, toattribs)
        } }
    } 
    return(branch)
}
```

For example, the following

```
b <- shinydashboard::box(collapsible = T)
searchreplaceit(b, "i", list(class="fa fa-minus"), "i", list(class="XXX"))
```

will search within `b` a tag `"i"` having (at least) attributes `class="fa fa-minus"`. When found, it is replaced with a tag `"i"` and attributes `class="XXX"`:

```
# <div class="col-sm-6">
#   <div class="box">
#     <div class="box-header">
#       <div class="box-tools pull-right">
#         <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse">
#           <i class="XXX" role="presentation" aria-label="minus icon"></i>
#         </button>
#       </div>
#     </div>
#     <div class="box-body"></div>
#   </div>
# </div>
```

The search goes until the whole object has been scanned.

The only difficulties are (1) that objects produced by shinyObjects interleaves both `shiny.tag` and `list` sub-objects; (2) some of the elements are sometimes NULL.

The function is a recursive function; for any branch (object of class `shiny.tag`) or sublist visited, it returns the modified element.