# Set a default value in shiny inputs (in case the user deletes it in the UI)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, numeric-input

I am trying to set a default (or fallback) value for `numericInput()` in my shiny app to prevent `NAs`.

I am aware that the `NA` can be dealt with later in the **server.r**, but was wondering if there is a more elegant way of replacing the value within the input whenever a user deletes it in the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the `validate` package with `need()` (see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246439/restrict-input-type-in-shiny-field)), but here is something simpler and closer to what you are asking for:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, session, output) {
  
  dafault_val <- 0
  
  observe({
    if (!is.numeric(input$obs)) {
      updateNumericInput(session, "obs", value = dafault_val)
    }
  })
  
  output$value <- renderText({ input$obs })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work quite well indeed. Would multiple of these observe calls have a substantial effect on the performance of an shiny app?

Comment: I usually use quite a bunch of them and they don't seem to impact performance that much. Setting rules through `validate` or `shinyvalidate` wouldn't probably be (much) more efficient for simple stuff like this. I am not a `shiny` expert, so can't really provide any guarantees here.

Comment: In my case I would have about 20 Inputs where I would need to create an observe({ }).

Comment: You could try benchmarking the solutions (https://mastering-shiny.org/performance.html), but I would not expect this to be the bottleneck of an app as people are inputting values sequentially anyway. Overoptimizing already fast methods is often worse than ignoring performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using library([shinyvalidate](https://rstudio.github.io/shinyvalidate/index.html)), which is [RStudios "official" way](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/927#issuecomment-849664075) to solve this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyvalidate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "myNumber",
    label = "My number",
    value = 0,
    min = 0,
    max = 10
  ),
  textOutput("myText")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  iv <- InputValidator$new()
  iv$add_rule("myNumber", sv_required(message = "Number must be provided"))
  iv$add_rule("myNumber", sv_gte(0))
  iv$add_rule("myNumber", sv_lte(10))
  iv$enable()
  
  output$myText <- renderText({
    req(iv$is_valid())
    input$myNumber
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```